# Why is the Java and DB time-zone automatically changed?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, tomcat

I found an unknown problem while using java, spring, mysql.

mysql time zone = UTC.

and tomcat time zone = KST. like this code

```java
    @PostConstruct
    void postConstruct() {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Seoul"));
    }
```

Now, let’s check the Java time zone.

```java
TimeZone aDefault = TimeZone.getDefault();
System.out.println("aDefault = " + aDefault); // 'Asia/Seoul' It is what i wanted.

LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
System.out.println("localDateTime = " + localDateTime); // It is based on KST. what i wanted
```

**The problem is the moment I run the query on the db.**

// jpa is used and the grammar is omitted for semantic interpretation.

```java
// jpa
@Query("select a from A a where datetime >= : dateTime")
```

It was clearly confirmed that the query was executed in KST time, and the DB was saved in UTC time, but the values ​​in the DB were imported that match the conditions based on KST.

I can't really figure out how to calculate the DB time automatically.

For example, the application stores data at 10 o'clock and the value is stored at 1 o'clock(-9) in the DB.

I run the query right away, so I checked that it goes out to `select ~ where datetime >= 10:00:00` .

Then, since it is stored at 1 o'clock in the DB, it is normal to not import the data, but the data is imported normally.

Comment: What is the type of the `datetime` column? Is it with or without timezone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not use either Spring Boot or JPA. But I can give you some general points.

Your question is not precisely clear, but it seems you are trying to find rows in a table using a column of a data type akin to the SQL type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. For JDBC 4.2, you should be using `OffsetDateTime` class as it is the type matching that of the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

In straight JDBC code, I would be using a prepared statement with `?` placeholders with SQL like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM some_table
WHERE some_column >= ?
;
```

In the prepared statement, pass the `OffsetDateTime` as the value for the `?`.

```java
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```java
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

You can adjust that `OffsetDateTime` into a particular time zone. Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.

```java
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

Regarding your sample code… I cannot think of any situation where calling `LocalDateTime.now()` is the right thing to do, as that type cannot represent a moment, is not a point on the timeline. Instead, use `Instant.now()` for the current moment as seen in UTC, or `ZonedDateTime.now()` for the current moment as seen in the JVM’s current default time zone. For JDBC work, use `OffsetDateTime` as seen above.

You said:

> For example, the application stores data at 10 o'clock and the value is stored at 1 o'clock(-9) in the DB.

Either:

- You are using the incorrect data type on your column. To record moments, specific points on the timeline, you must use `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, not `WITHOUT`.

  - In MySQL, this means you need to be using [`TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html), not `DATETIME`.
- You are using opinionated middleware or tooling with the anti-feature of injecting a time zone adjustment upon retrieval from the database.

Never use `TimeZone` class. That class is part of the legacy date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes. Specifically replaced by [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) & [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html).

Lastly, I just barely mention this caution: If you are booking future appointments or something similar, this is the wrong approach. If you want appointments where the time-of-day stays fixed even if politicians change the rules of your time zone (so a dental appointment at 3 PM stays at 3 PM regardless of changes to Daylight Saving Time or other clock manipulations), then you should be using *two* columns, one akin to the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`. And use a second column of a textual type holding the name of the intended time zone. When needing to dynamically create a calendar where you need specific moments, combine the two values at runtime to produce a `ZonedDateTime` object. That moment is to be used only briefly at runtime, never stored. This topic has been addressed many times on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.